# nmap Not Working with CIDR Notation on LAN

Tags: nmap, host-discovery

I'm doing a simple host discovery on my LAN and noticed that CIDR notation does not report any hosts. I scoured `man nmap` with no findings in differences between using a CIDR range and any other range.

`sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.*` and `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0-255` both report the correct number of live hosts.

`sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1/24` reports 0 hosts.

I noticed the latter takes a lot longer to run as well. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the final segment of the IP address.

It should be 192.168.1.1/24 this basically says to NMAP scan the entire class C network space of 255 IP addresses.

This is correct CIDR notation and assumes your LAN is on 192.168.1.

For more info on CIDR check out the Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: Why is that last digit required if it's not part of the significant range of bits? Just proper CIDR notation? In forwarding tables they do not write out the non-significant bits normally.

Comment: No that is correct CIDR notation.

Comment: FYI for anyone else reading this question, it does not need to be `.1` at the end, it could be any number between 0-255.

Answer (score 2):

Nmap (as well as most command-line tools on Linux, Windows, and other OSs) uses the [POSIX `inet_aton` or `inet_addr` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html) which turns a string IP address into a 32-bit number. The rules it uses are complicated, but `A.B.C` is turned into the equivalent of `A.B.0.C`, so your target specification of `192.168.1/24` is really scanning `192.168.0.1/24`, which is not the network you intended.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo and I fixed the question. The issue was the string IP address translation.

Comment: Cool. I updated the answer to remove that mention so that it's clearer.